# check if s2polygon contains s2cap

Tags: java, geometry

I'm using the [Google S2 library](https://code.google.com/archive/p/s2-geometry-library/) in java. There is a method in the S2Polygon class to check if another s2polygon is contained in the current one.

```
/**
* Return true if this polygon contains the given other polygon, i.e. if
* polygon A contains all points contained by polygon B.
*/
public boolean contains(S2Polygon b)
```

Is there a way to check if an S2Cap is contained in an S2Polygon? It looks like if I convert S2Cap to a list of S2Cells, then I can check contains on each of the cells, but am looking to see if there is a better way, as conversion to cells is an expensive process.